# Run a batch file from php code

Tags: php, batch-file

i have a batch file that contains a command to record a live stream from server, i have tried it in CMD.exe, it work fine.

I need now to run this file from php code (by a button "Record"), but i don't get any output.

please can you check my code and try to give me a solution please :

1 - the batch file code :

```
@echo off
vlc input stream --sout "#duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=mov,dst=output file.mp4}"
@echo off
```

2 - the php file code:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("C:\\wamp\\www\\CMD\\filebat.bat");
echo exec($file);
echo "Done!";
?>
```

3 - Another php code:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("C:\\wamp\\www\\CMD\\filebat.bat");
$output = exec($file);
print_r($output);
?>
```

4 - Another php code :

```
<?php
echo exec('C:\\wamp\\www\\CMD\\filebat.bat');
?>
```

i tried these 3 php code but i don't get any output.

kindly, can you help me to find the best solution how i Run a batch file from php code ??

regards,

Answer (score 0):

4.) Should work. Check php.ini/phpinfo if SAFE_MODE is OFF.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: what should be the status of SAFE_MODE ?

Comment: Dear Michael, please can you check the syntax of batch file (command syntax),  i think that the error could be in it. thank you for your help my friend

Comment: if i try to manually run the batch file, the command work fine and the batch file work fine also, so i mean in the previous comment the syntax between php and batch file. regards,

Comment: Safe Mode should be OFF.

Comment: Try something simple to execute first, like echo exec('dir');

Comment: i have tried ('dir'), i obtained this : 2 Dir(s) 260,680,650,752 bytes free

Comment: and does exec('vlc input stream --sout "#duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=mov,dst=output file.mp4}"); // work?

Comment: Dear Michael, i have puted in the batch file echo off dir echo off, and i have executed the batch file by php, it's work fine now. so, we still to know why when i put the duplicate command, it does not run.